# How to select record that contains only certain character SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have some records as below

```
AB01234-T100
AB01235-RE-T200
AB01236-O-T100
AB01237-O
AB01238
```

I only want the first record as the output. What I can think of is to specify that the record must contain A,B and T in the string but have no idea how to code it.

`WHERE MyColumn LIKE 'AB_____-T__'` seems to be the closest match but in some special occasion, there might be more character in the middle.

Comment: `where MyColumn like '%-M-%' or MyColumn like '%-O-%'`? Or `not like` - I wasn't clear whether by filter you want to keep them or exclude them.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to exclude those -RE -O-

Comment: So as I said, use `not like` instead.

Comment: The query result doesn't seems to be perfect in my case, it returns me some record like `AB01238-O`

Comment: you need `and` - not `or` - but simpler as `where MyColumn not like '%-[OM]-%'`

Comment: I tried `WHERE MyColumn NOT LIKE '%-[A-Z]-%'`, but the result doesnt meet what i want

Comment: I've no idea why you tried that. No one here suggested that as far as I can see. Why would you expect `[A-Z]` to treat `O` and `M` differently as needed?

Comment: `[OM]` will look for only O and M isn't it? But I might have other character too, and it can be 2 character sometimes instead of just 1

Comment: Well your original question *was* "How can I filter out those with the M and O in the middle?" so don't be surprised about answers telling you how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply multiple LIKE conditions to achieve the result

```sql
declare @TABLE TABLE(charvalue VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @TABLE values
('AB01234-T100')
,('AB01235-RE-T200')
,('AB01236-O-T100')
,('AB01237-O')
,('AB01238');

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
WHERE charvalue LIKE 'AB%-T%' and 
charvalue not like 'AB%-[^T]%'
```

```
+--------------+
|  charvalue   |
+--------------+
| AB01234-T100 |
+--------------+
```